# How to increase Postfix SMTP log retention?

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

I'm running Postfix Sendmail 2.6.6 and my SMTP logs seem to only be going back one month. How can I configure it to retain logs for a longer period of time?

BTW I'm referring to logs in \var\logs\maillog*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postfix never throws logs away, that is logrotate's job. Check `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` and configure it to your liking.

Comment: Do I need to restart any service to apply the changes?

Comment: no, logrotate runs as a cronjob. no need to restart anything.

Comment: Nevermind answered it myself. Thanks for the help.